# Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2

Tags: c#

Below is my code. The line inside `try` throws below error

> *Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.Tuple`3[System.String,System.String,System.String],Syste>m.Boolean]'
>   to type 'System.Tuple`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]'*

Why I am not able to cast in following way? And how can I do that?

```
        List<Tuple<string, string, string>> customers = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
        customers.Add(new Tuple<string,string,string>("Saroj", "India", "Mumbai"));
        customers.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>("Robin", "US", "New York"));

        List<string> filterNames = new List<string>();
        filterNames.Add("Saroj");

        foreach (string name in filterNames)
        {
            var customer = customers.Select(s => s.Item1 == name);
            try
            {
                Tuple<string, string, string> item = (Tuple<string, string, string>)customer;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `customers.Select(s => s.Item1 == name)` return `IEnumerable` of objects not single object. Use `FirstOrDefault`, `First`, `SingleOrDefault` or `Single` according you buisness logic to get object from `IEnumerable` of objects

Answer (score 0):

you have to put where and you will get your output.No need to cast.

```
foreach (string name in filterNames)
        {
            var customer = customers.Where(s => s.Item1 == name);
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I need some further processing after that. Like removing the item from `customers`. If I will only write `var` (without cast), the `Remove` method throws exception.